# ruby regex if-statement

Tags: ruby, regex

I expect this to return `"appleay"`, but I'm getting nothing. So I'm assuming that there is something wrong with my `if`-statement or regex.

```
translate_this = "apple"
if translate_this[0] == /^[aeiou]/ # first letter is a vowel
  puts translate_this + 'ay'
else
end
```

Comment: use `=~` ..............

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

This won't need an if statement.

```
> translate_this = "apple"
> translate_this.sub(/^([aeiou].*)/, '\1ay')
=> "appleay"
```

or

```
> translate_this = "apple"
> if translate_this[0] =~ /[aeiou]/
>   puts translate_this + 'ay'
> else
> end
appleay
=> nil
```

Here you don't need to use `^` start of the line anchor because you're actually checking the character at 0th index (ie, first character).

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to use `=~` instead of `==`

It should have read

```
if translate_this[0] =~ /^[aeiou]/
```